# Pine Script V5 - tracking last "signal" given

Tags: pine-script

Honestly cannot find any information on this or where to start, I'm extremely new to Pine Script so please go easy.

What I am trying to do is this:

- Track the higher/highs and lower/lows (this much I could find examples of so it's sorted, and I can plot them as is without issue)
- Consider entry valid if last signal was one of my choosing at the time of the above

Example of what I have so far, filled in the blanks with just text for now:

```
higherhigh = filteredtopf == false ? false : ( valuewhen(filteredtopf == true, high[2], 1) < valuewhen(filteredtopf == true, high[2], 0) and valuewhen(filteredtopf == true, high[2], 2) < valuewhen(filteredtopf == true, high[2], 0))
lowerhigh = filteredtopf == false ? false : ( valuewhen(filteredtopf == true, high[2], 1) > valuewhen(filteredtopf == true, high[2], 0) and valuewhen(filteredtopf == true, high[2], 2) > valuewhen(filteredtopf == true, high[2], 0))
higherlow = filteredbotf == false ? false : ( valuewhen(filteredbotf == true, low[2], 1) < valuewhen(filteredbotf == true, low[2], 0) and valuewhen(filteredbotf == true, low[2], 2) < valuewhen(filteredbotf == true, low[2], 0))
lowerlow = filteredbotf == false ? false : ( valuewhen(filteredbotf == true, low[2], 1) > valuewhen(filteredbotf == true, low[2], 0) and valuewhen(filteredbotf == true, low[2], 2) > valuewhen(filteredbotf == true, low[2], 0))

lastSignal = "Last signal given from above - highigh, lowerhigh, higherlow, or lowerlow"
buySignal = higherlow and "last signal is higher high"
sellSignal = lowerhigh and "last signal is lower low"
```

[Image for easier viewing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFFmh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort this eventually, example with only these conditions below.

```
var lastsignal = "test"
if higherhigh
    lastsignal := "higherhigh"
if lowerhigh
    lastsignal := "lowerhigh"
if higherlow
    lastsignal := "higherlow"
if lowerlow
    lastsignal := "lowerlow"

buySignal = lastsignal[1] == "higherhigh" or lastsignal[1] == "higherlow"
sellSignal = lastsignal[1] == "lowerlow" or lastsignal[1] == "lowerhigh"
```